# Security of my modem from resets

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, ip, modem

I successfully configured my old (Optilink) modem to connect to my internet connection. So there is the primary modem and then there's the Optilink modem. I have also set a new password to access the modem settings.

Every modem has a reset button which if pressed and held long enough will successfully reset the modem.

My question(s):

1. Will the password to access modem settings that I set also get reset if the modem is reset? This can be figured by simply resetting it myself. However, I have configured the modem now and I do not want to jinx it again.
2. If the answer to above is a YES, then pretty much anyone can reset the Optilink modem and change its settings including the WiFi password. What additional security settings can be set to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, holding down the reset button on the modem will fully factory reset it, resetting the password to its UI to whatever it defaults to.

You can't really prevent someone from resetting the router via the button in most cases, but you could try putting a physical barrier around it, but if someone *really* wanted to get around it, it wouldn't be much use.

**You should assume if someone has physical access to a device (be that a router, laptop, etc) that they will gain access to it** - it's up to you to keep it in a secure location to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks @pigeonburger. Appreciate the response :) That means I have taken as much care as can be taken with regard to technicalities. I note your answer.